# Indicating selected text even when the textarea doesn't have the focus

Tags: css, focus, textarea, textselection

In both Firefox and Chrome, the text selection of a text field (= the range of text that's selected in the field) is only indicated when that field has the focus. The selection does *exist* even when the field doesn't have the focus — it's queryable from JavaScript, and it becomes visible again if the field regains the focus in a way that doesn't change the selection — but, it's not visible to the user. (See example code snippet below. Highlight whatever text you want in the `<textarea>` field; then use Tab and Shift+Tab to transfer focus away and back. Your text only appears selected while the field has the focus.)

Is there a way to override this behavior?

Some notes:

- I tried using [CSS's `::selection` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) with rules to set the color and background-color, but that didn't help; the rules were only applied while the field had the focus.
- I'd prefer to do it with just HTML/CSS/JavaScript (no user intervention), but I'm open to using browser settings if necessary.
- I don't care whether the selection looks the *same* without focus as with focus, as long as it's *visible* in both cases.
- I mainly need to support Firefox, but if possible I'd like to support other modern browsers as well.
- I don't care whether the selection is indicated when it has length zero (= when it's just a cursor position).

```html
<textarea rows="2" cols="15">Hello, world!</textarea>
```

Comment: I can't imagine this is possible without using a `contentEditable` element in place of the `textarea`, but I'm intrigued as to the possibilities of being proven wrong :)

Comment: I'd suggest using `contentEditable` too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to use the specific selection elements for firefox in CSS? Looks like the element is only implemented in Firefox this way (Version 2-61 after that it is fixed):

```
::-moz-selection {

}
```

Comment: No dice -- that behaves the same as `::selection` (I'm on version 67) -- but thanks for trying. :-)